# Pandas - Create a new column with apply for float indexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas 13.0 and I'm trying to create a new colum using apply() and a function name foo().

My dataframe is as follow:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({
         'a':[ 0.0,  0.1,  0.2,  0.3], 
         'b':[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0], 
         'c':[ 1.0,  2.0,  3.0,  4.0]
     })

df.set_index(df['a'], inplace=True)
```

So my dataframe is:

```
in: print df

out:
           a    b     c
      a
      0.0  0.0  10.0  1.0
      0.1  0.1  20.0  2.0
      0.2  0.2  30.0  3.0
      0.3  0.3  40.0  4.0
```

My function is as follow:

```
def foo(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1*arg2
```

Now I want to create a column name 'd' using foo();

```
df['d'] = df.apply(foo(df['b'], df['c']), axis=1)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 0.0')
```

How can I use pandas.apply() with foo() for index that are made of float?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to process this row-wise but you are passing series as arguements which is wrong you could do it this way:

```
In [7]:

df['d'] = df.apply(lambda row: foo(row['b'], row['c']), axis=1)
df
Out[7]:
       a   b  c    d
a                   
0.0  0.0  10  1   10
0.1  0.1  20  2   40
0.2  0.2  30  3   90
0.3  0.3  40  4  160
```

A better way would be to just call your function direct:

```
In [8]:

df['d'] = foo(df['b'], df['c'])
df
Out[8]:
       a   b  c    d
a                   
0.0  0.0  10  1   10
0.1  0.1  20  2   40
0.2  0.2  30  3   90
0.3  0.3  40  4  160
```

The advantage with the above method is that it is vectorised and will perform the operation on the whole series rather than a row at a time.

```
In [15]:

%timeit df['d'] = df.apply(lambda row: foo(row['b'], row['c']), axis=1)
%timeit df['d'] = foo(df['b'], df['c'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 270 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 214 µs per loop
```

Not much difference here, now compare with a 400,000 row df:

```
In [18]:

%timeit df['d'] = df.apply(lambda row: foo(row['b'], row['c']), axis=1)
%timeit df['d'] = foo(df['b'], df['c'])
1 loops, best of 3: 5.84 s per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 8.68 ms per loop
```

So you see here ~672x speed up.

Comment: many thanks for your answer. it works now. Also, very useful the speed comparison. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. As a general rule avoid using `apply` if there is a vectorised operation, for basic operations such as add/subtract/div and multiply there are built in operator support for these that are many orders of magnitude faster.