# Python Pandas add new column based on existing column - "Length of values does not match length of index"

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing Pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

[image]

I want to create a new column in the dataframe that contains a dictionary with word/word counts derived from an existing column that contains a body of text.

I have got this working on a single row from the dataframe with the following transformation:

```
from collections import Counter
obama['word_count'] = [dict(Counter(" ".join(obama['text']).split(" ")).items())]
```

creates new column that contains the expected dictionary.

[image]

and while this works it gives the following warning:

```
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
```

When I use the same transformation above with entire dataframe:

```
people['word_count'] = [dict(Counter(" ".join(people['text']).split(" ")).items())]
```

it fails with error message:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

This appears to be an issue of indexes not matching. None of the 'text' values are missing so it is not getting out of sync that way.

I've gone to the [url](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) in the Pandas warning and cannot grasp what it is getting at.

I've also done my Google searches but I do not feel found results apply to my issue.

What is need to make this add column procedure work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (at least) two way to do this :

- using a *list comprehension* with something like :

  `people['word_count'] = \
      [dict(Counter(i[1]['text'].split(" ")).items()) for i in people.iterrows()]`
- using the `apply` method of the DataFrame, with something like :

  `people['word_count'] = people.apply(
      lambda x: dict(Counter(x['test'].split(" ")).items()), axis=1)`

(The second method appears to be a bit faster but also don't seems to be working on the OP DataFrame; some details are in comments)

Comment: Yes thanks that works. However, I was trying to do it direct without apply()  Apparently apply() is much slower on big datasets than going direct. See this other [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719401/pandas-create-a-new-column-with-apply-for-float-indexed-dataframe)

Comment: Actually apply produces the `<built-in method values of dict object at 0x00...` output. So apply() may not be good for this particular transformation.

Comment: I also tend to not use apply but it can be convenient (for readability or when using certain functions for example). Anyway in my test (on python 3.4 / pandas 0.17) the following statment ```df['word count'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict(Counter(x['test'].split(" ")).items()), axis=1)``` make a new column with the word count (not sure why you use join *and* split on your text). You can also use list comprehension to avoid apply, like ```df['word count'] = [dict(Counter(i[1]['text'].split(" ")).items()) for i in df.iterrows()]```

Comment: You are right, join isn't needed. i see now Counter works fine on split words without needing commas to separate them.  List comprehension works perfectly. Apply still outputs `<built-in method values of dict object at 0x00...` Quick timer test shows apply is bit faster than direct method: **apply method** `1 loops, best of 3: 14.6 s per loop`  **direct method** `1 loops, best of 3: 18.2 s per loop` .  My data has ~60k rows and mean of 314 words per row.

Comment: Can you add both methods to orig answer and I will mark as answer. Thanks for help!